# MVC with code first doesn't start

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using code first to develop my database for my MVC app. Here's the connection string:

> <add name="OrtundWebConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=OrtundWeb; User Id=sa; Password=sa;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

It uses SQL Authentication because for reasons I've yet to determine, Windows Auth doesn't allow me to do anything on the server...

Here's Application_Start():

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        OrtundDB.InitializeDB();
    }
```

This class calls `db.Database.Initialize(true);` and runs a method I wrote to add some default information into the database

```
public static class OrtundDB
{
    private static OrtundDBContext db = new OrtundDBContext();

    public static void InitializeDB()
    {
        db.Database.Initialize(true);
        db.InitializeDB();
    }
}
```

Here's the DBContext class I wrote that's being used. This exists in another project which is referenced in the MVC project:

```
internal class OrtundDBContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        // modelBuilder.Configuration.Adds()
    }

    public OrtundDBContext()
        : base("OrtundWebConnectionString")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<OrtundDBContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<OrtundDBContext>());
    }

    public void InitializeDB()
    {
        // inserts the default data - an admin user account and information for user roles
    }

    // DbSet calls here
}
```

I've previously built an MVC app with this same methodology, and that one works. This, however, doesn't even execute `Application_Start()` every time.

On the odd occasion where it has executed Application_Start, it went all the way through to execute `db.Database.Initialize(true);` at which point, it just never seemed to end. I got no errors, but the action didn't seem to complete.

I'm a bit of a novice when it comes to MVC so I have no idea what the problem could be or how to fix it.

Any assistance to fix the problem (and possibly explanation as to what might cause it) will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you run the application, and `Application_Start` doesn't get called, what exactly happens?

Comment: As far as I'm aware (almost certain I'm wrong), Application_Start is the very first thing that happens. I put a breakpoint on it which was never hit... As far as I can see, it just continues to wait for the server (using VS development server for debugging)

Comment: That should definitely be one of the first things that runs (quite possibly the first), I've never had an application do that. Usually when that kind of thing happens (act of god) I stop for the day then start over in the morning ;) All joking aside though, I have absolutely no idea what would cause that.

Comment: To force App_Start(), kill the server (IIS express) first.

Comment: That call to `Database.SetInitializer<>()` inside the Context ctor might be a little late. Make it the 1st statement in the static `InitializeDB()`

Comment: And rename one of those `InitializeDB()`s

Comment: @HenkHolterman Turns out it was using a server that was already running... I stopped that, started a new one and it worked :) outside of some weird schema issues, everything's fine now. Make an answer, I'll +1

Comment: You should normally be able to develop and even deploy to a running server. So dig a little deeper (it might happen again) and once solved you can post a self-answer.

Comment: It hasn't happened since... I've tried numerous times

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the issues lies with the expectation you have on `Application_Start`.
`Application_Start` is called once for the application being loaded into the app pool on IIS.
Only when the app pool is recycled or IIS is restarted will it be called again.

Take 10-15mins to read [IIS pipeline](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/introduction-to-iis/introduction-to-iis-architecture)
It will help with what is going on.

I had a nasty bug due to my false expectations about threads and requests.

alternatives to Consider and test in debug to see if they suit you:

The **INIT** in Global.asax

```
 public override void Init() {
        base.Init();
        // handlers managed by ASP.Net during Forms authentication
        BeginRequest += new EventHandler(BeginRequestHandler);
      //  PostAuthorizeRequest += new EventHandler(PostAuthHandler);
        EndRequest += new EventHandler(EndRequestHandler);
    }
```

***Better: A single baseController for all your controllers*** so as to control bootstrap each call.

```
   public class SomeController : MyBaseMvcController{
    // whatever as usual....
   }


[System.Web.Mvc.Authorize]
[MyMVCFilter]  // see the filter below.  Get the MVC pipeline to call your code on Executing
public abstract class MyBaseMvcController : Controller
{
    protected MyBaseMvcController () {
          // a place to get a NEW uow or new Context ....
    }
}

public class MyMVCFilter : System.Web.Mvc.ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) {

     // a useful bootstrap option when you need the httpContext for bootstrap.
     BootStrapHttp(filterContext.HttpContext);
     base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

    }


}
```